# Invalid Form Body guild_id[NUMBER_TYPE_COERCE]: Value "undefined" is not snowflake

Tags: discord.js

S[50035]: Invalid Form Body
guild_id[NUMBER_TYPE_COERCE]: Value "undefined" is not snowflake.
at Q.runRequest (E:\Capital Bot\node_modules@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:7:581)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async Q.queueRequest (E:\Capital Bot\node_modules@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:5:2942) {
rawError: {
code: 50035,
errors: { guild_id: [Object] },
message: 'Invalid Form Body'
},
code: 50035,
status: 400,
method: 'put',
[image]

i tried everything nothing works

Comment: You should do some basic debugging. Have you checked the value of `guildId`?

Comment: yes i did the bot will be private for one server so its one guild id